# MOD13Q1 data (2008-2012)

Tags: envi

i ordered MOD13Q1 images (2008 -2012) from NASA and there came in hdf format, now i want to extract only NDVI images but the hdf made up of all vegetation indices data.Please how can i solve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you please *edit* your question and be more specific what your desired outcome is? I presume want to extract the NDVI subdatasets from all MOD13Q1 images with an IDL script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HEG tool which converts the hdf format into tiff images and you get options while converting so you can choose the NDVI option in that tool to get the NDVI image.